# What creates the orange hue when there is wildfire smoke?

Tags: optics, visible-light, scattering, atmospheric-science

I find a variety of opposing arguments on the internet:

1. That this is due to Rayleigh scattering, which "removes" the blue light from reaching our eyes. This is similar to how the sunset looks red --- all blue light is "lost" and only red light survives its journey to our eyes.
2. That this is due to Rayleigh scattering, which in this case, scatters not just the blue, but also the red and orange light due to the (a) thick layer of smoke and/or (b) large size of smoke particles. This scattered light reaches our eyes, making the smoke look orange. This is similar to how the sky looks blue --- the scattered blue light reaches our eyes.
3. That this is due to Mie scattering which happens when the particles are large, like in smoke. Mie scattering, unlike Rayleigh scatter has an allegedly opposite dependence on wavelength, and thus scatters red light more than blue.
4. That this can't be due to Mie scattering, which is largely wave-length-*in*dependent unlike Rayleigh. Most Mie scattering effects makes the object looks hazy white e.g., fog, or the glare around the sun.

Which of this is true? What scattering is it? How does scattering affect what color we view? How do you decide which narrative applies: "color X scatters and reaches our eyes and so everything looks like color X" or is it "color X scatters and is lost, so you only see all-but-X"?

Comment: Thanks, could you elaborate a bit more? Is Mie causing all wavelengths to scatter? Or only red/orange wavelengths?  If it's the former, why is the smoke looking reddish and not white?

Comment: I only meant to correct your spelling of Mie. I don't have time for a detailed answer right now, but I believe the answer is that smoke particles absorb more strongly at shorter (i.e. blue) wavelengths, so it's not just scattering.

Comment: NASA seem to side with Rayleigh - [Red Skies in U.S. Pacific Northwest Caused by Smoke from Siberian Fires](https://www.nasa.gov/image-feature/goddard/red-skies-in-us-pacific-northwest-caused-by-smoke-from-siberian-fires)

Comment: Possible duplicate of https://physics.stackexchange.com/questions/722675/why-the-sunset-is-red-and-a-possible-experiment/722712#722712